# Upgrading Mercurial on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

This [site](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) is advertising 3.6.2 as the latest version of TortoiseHg.

When I `apt-get update` and `apt-get install tortoisehg` the latest version I get is 3.0:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy tortoisehg
tortoisehg:
  Installed: 3.0-0ppa1
  Candidate: 3.0-0ppa1
  Version table:
 *** 3.0-0ppa1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.10-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

This is using https://launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa.

I tried using https://launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/releases but I get HTTP 404 when I try to `apt-get update`.

Is there not binary support for Ubuntu? Recommendations for building should this be the case?